# How to import active directory SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, active-directory, import, active-directory-import

I'm new to SharePoint.I have a ,trial 365 Enterprise E3 Developer account with 2016 SharePoint site.I tried to find setting for the active directory import but i could not, is it because i have a trial licence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use Active Directory Connect to sync your on-premises Active Directory.  I recently did this on a trial account and I don't think there is any restriction, obviously, you only get 5 user licenses so won't be able to assign to more than 5 users in your AD.

Information on how to setup is [here](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Set-up-directory-synchronization-for-Office-365-1b3b5318-6977-42ed-b5c7-96fa74b08846) and more information about AAD Connect is [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnect)